# iPad Notification Center Widget Unresponsiveness

Tags: ipad, ios5, widget, uislider

I made a widget for the iOS 5 notification center that implements a `UISlider` along with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

The gestureRecognizer works fine, but the `UISlider` is very unresponsive and will only move a small amount if the thumb is touched and dragged.

It will not move until another touch down. Is there a way to circumvent this limitation? (I didn't load any views above it, it works fine on the iPhone and iPod Touch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix it.
You should set the superviews gesturerecogniser's cancelTouchesInView property to NO on viewWillAppear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    if (deviceIsIPAD()) {
        UIView *list = [[objc_getClass("SBBulletinListController") sharedInstance] listView];
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in list.gestureRecognizers) {
            gr.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        }
    }
```

}